# Expandable list is not Expanding With AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener in java Class

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i am creating a class in which i am using Scrolling toolbar with expandable list,every thing is working fine but when ever i click on expandable list it does not expand as i needed please help me out if i am missing some thing.
i have created Adapter class and used it in my main class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
{

    Context context;
    List<String> listGroup;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listItems;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> listGroup, HashMap<String,List<String>>
            listItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listGroup = listGroup;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listGroup.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return this.listItems.get(this.listGroup.get(i)).size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i)
    { return this.listGroup.get(i);  }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {return this.listItems.get(this.listGroup.get(i)).get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1)
    {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View views, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String group = (String) getGroup(i);
        if (views== null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            views = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group,null);
        }

        TextView textView = views.findViewById(R.id.list_parent);
        textView.setText(group);
        return views;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int i, final int i1, boolean b, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final String child = (String) getChild(i,i1);

        if (view == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items,null);

        }
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
        textView.setText(child);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The main class is Scrolling Class in which I am using Expandable list

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    // Expandable list Definations
    ExpandableListView expandable_list;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listitems;
    List<String> listHeader;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

        //FindViewById of Expandable Data List
        expandable_list = findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
        listHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listitems = new HashMap<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, listHeader, listitems);
        expandable_list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        initlistData();


    private void initlistData() {

        listHeader.add(getString(R.string.group11));

        String[] aray;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        aray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group1);
        for (String item : aray) {
            list.add(item);
        }

        listitems.put(listHeader.get(0), list);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

i have edited the main code and just paste the main code only main problem is that every thing is working but when ever i click on my expandable list then it doesn't Scroll as per required.

Answer (score 0):

you have initialized your `lists` first, then set `adapter` to your `expandablelistview`!

```
        expandable_list = findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
        listHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        listitems = new HashMap<>();

        initlistData();  // =============> call this method here!

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, listHeader, listitems);
        expandable_list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank You, Sir will try now only and will report back :)

Comment: YES THNKU FOR YOUR CONCERN

Comment: can uh help my friend with this problem he is facing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913282/custom-recyclerview-using-adapter

Comment: I'll review your friend problem